# RSpec controller tests returning 301 in every request

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm building a build server running on Jenkins to test a rails app on every commit to 'master' in git.

My problem is: I've created a new "staging" environment so the build can be run in a real database, connecting to real SQS queues and stuff, really testing all integration points of this system but somehow when I run `rake spec` or `rspec ./spec` using `RAILS_ENV='staging'` every test of every controller receives a `301` response for the test.

Some JSON-returning tests receive a HTML with a response body as `<html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/SOME_PATH">redirected</a></body></html>`.

I just can't find a reason why these same tests run normally under `RAILS_ENV='test'` and are failing under the new staging environment.

Any clue of what I must've forgotten or haven't done so this can work?

Comment: Did you find the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a lot of things, I would look for some sort of authenticaion system that gets bypassed during `Test, but not during another environment such as`Staging`.